# SQL Server 2016 query Azure AD

Tags: sql-server-2016, azure

I need to query our (Azure) AD to get a user username based on on an email address I am being passed and then write it to a table ideally via an SP.

From my brief bit of reading, Azure AD supports Graph as does SQL Server 2017 and in theory I could use that to integrate the two, unfortunately, I am using SQL Server 2016 and the amount of testing required to upgrade to a more modern SQL version would probably be more than I could justify for this (small) project.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Am I going to have to resort to calling an external power shell script?